# Searching using the last 4 digits

Tags: c#

Just needed a tip for additional search functionality. I can search using the full 9 digit ItemID (123456789) but unable to add  searching capability using the last 4 digits of ItemID on top of full digit search? ItemID does not hold fixed number. It should pick last 4 digit from any ItemID number.

```
  public ActionResult Search(SearchEmployeeModel searchEmployeeModel) 
   {
        searchEmployeeModel.ItemID = searchEmployeeModel.ItemID != null ? searchEmployeeModel.ItemID.Replace("'", "''") : searchEmployeeModel.ItemID;            
        searchEmployeeModel.First_Name = searchEmployeeModel.First_Name != null ? searchEmployeeModel.First_Name.Replace("'", "''") : searchEmployeeModel.First_Name;
                
    
List<SearchEmployeeModel> searchResult = repository.GetSearchItem(searchEmployeeModel.ItemID, searchEmployeeModel.First_Name);
    
   Session["SearchEmployeeModelHome"] = searchEmployeeModel;
   Session["searchResultHome"] = searchResult;
    
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
    
   }

public List<SearchEmployeeModel> GetSearchItem(string ItemID, string First_Name)
{
var searchItem = _db.Query<SearchEmployeeModel>("usp_SearchItem", new
{
@ItemID = ItemID
@First_Name = First_Name,    
}, null, true, 300, CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

return searchItem;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do this in C# or in SQL? If it's the latter, show us your current Stored Procedure.

Comment: Also this is not how your code looks how programmers usually read code. Please make sure you have formatted your code in the question, help us help you

Comment: I am trying to implement it using c#

Comment: Well, I doubt that that's what you want but in C#, you can achieve that using something like `str1.Substring(str1.Length - 4, 4) == str2.Substring(str2.Length - 4, 4)`. You'd also need to confirm that the `.Length` of both strings is `>= 4`. If that's not really what you're trying to do, please [edit] the question and try to clarify with a [repro].

Comment: I am trying to search the last 4 digit of ItemID (123456789) as a filter criteria.

Comment: Yet you still didn't format the code?

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear how you are getting the ids, but once you have the ids in a string list (or individual strings) one can use regex to determine if they are found by the last four digits in the string such as:

```
var ids = new List<string>() { "123456789", "678912345", "123456781", "666666789" };

var foundIds = ids.Where(id => Regex.IsMatch(id, "6789$")).ToList();
```

The pattern says look for `6789` at the end of the string `$`. Once processed `foundIds` will contain two ids of "123456789" and "666666789".

Comment: I got the ItemID from here : 
            @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Add(c => c.ItemID).Titled("ItemID");
                columns.Add(c => c.First_Name).Titled("First Name").Filterable(true);
               
            }).WithPaging(5).Sortable(true)

Comment: public class SearchItemModel
    {
        public string ItemID { get; set; }    
        public string First_Name { get; set; }     

    }

Comment: @Semi you are overcomplicating the question. StackOverflow is not about end results but fixing a single small item. I have addressed one item in the chain. It should give you enough to adapt it to your current design. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
string credit = "123456789"; ;
var last4 = credit.Substring(credit.Length - 4, 4);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation along with your code snippet instead of adding just the code.